# Is it possible to show the output on terminal while writing the output of a command to a file?

Tags: command-line, files, gnome-terminal, output

I am running a command say `nmap www.somesite.com>file.txt` so that i can get the output to file.txt. But if I do so, I am not able to see the output of that command on terminal. Is it possible to make it visble on terminal also.

I know the usage of `tee`, but I wish to do this specifically in this way.

Comment: I am not looking for one another command. I wish to know whether it is possible to do this by that command itself. I tried verbose but not working.

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is saying it is not possible? Is he not asking to redirect stderr to stdout? I have tested my answer and it seems to do what he asks.

Comment: @cremefraiche No. Say I do `echo A>some.file.txt`. OP Wants `A` to appear on the screen and in the file as well.

Comment: Unless the specific command provides option itself to do this, it is not possible without `tee`. Even in such a case, the command will be doing the same thing `tee` is doing.

Comment: What's wrong with `tee`, which was designed exactly for this purpose?

Comment: Tee is perfect and I know it. But i was looking for an explicit answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to have command line view and redirect process at the same time

But you can use the following command to use both the process in sequence

```
nmap www.somesite.com && nmap www.somesite.com > file.txt
```

First it will execute the command in terminal and then it will save the output as a file

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is cool. But It doubles the overhead rite?

Comment: It is a bit incorrect to say "redirect process", as the shell will only redirect output, not the process, and hence it is very well possible to dump the same text at many places.

Comment: This runs the command twice. A very inefficient solution. Particularly with nmap, which may be very slow depending on options used and size of target network.

Answer (score 3):

`tee` is designed to split `STDIN` into a file and back out to `STDOUT`.

In simple terms, just pipe it through, like so:

```
nmap www.somesite.com | tee file.txt
```

---

The current accepted alternative involves running `nmap` twice which is a horrible idea.
You'd be better off running it once to file and then outputting the file.

```
nmap www.somesite.com > file.txt; cat file.txt
```

Comment: Please read the question completely. I was looking for an answer other than `tee`. Anyway thanks ;)

Comment: If you don't want tee, please explain *why* or what it is you're actually trying to do. Otherwise this is Ask Ubuntu, Ubuntu ships `tee`, therefore `tee` is always an option here.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what `tee` is for. Why do you not want to use that?

An alternative might be to capture the output, and echo it twice:

```
output=$(nmap localhost)
echo "$output"
echo "$output" > somefile.txt
```

However, in the special case of nmap, you can take advantage of it's output option -ox :

> ```
>       OUTPUT:
>          -oN/-oX/-oS/-oG <file>: Output scan in normal, XML, s|<rIpt kIddi3,
>             and Grepable format, respectively, to the given filename.
> ```

For example:

```
nmap -oN somefile.txt localhost
```

Seems to do exactly what you want: output to the terminal and also write to file.